# httpconnection in android

Tags: android, http

i have to query a jsp page from android
http://192.148.1.7:8000/testing.jsp?para1=5000&para2=4
if you run this query in a browser then it givs the result in xml but i am not able to establish the connection from android device.

this page will give results based on these para1 and para2 in form of xml
but this xml displays a message :-
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

so i need help to fetch the result from this xml via jsp query. If somebody is familiar pls help....need it asap

Comment: Can the android device actually connect to the webserver? What does the network look like, is this WiFi? Can you ping the android from the webserver? Or if you can get to a terminal on the phone, can you ping the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) class

```
HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.148.1.7:8000/testing.jsp?"+
                    "para1=5000&para2=4");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
    mHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   //Log
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't connect to http://192.148.1.7:8000/testing.jsp?para1=5000&para2=4 from my (Chrome) browser. I get a `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.148.1.7:8000`.

That suggests there is something about connectivity between your browser and that site that is specific - and is not the same between your Android and that site. As Jonathon Reinhart suggests above, you probably do not have connectivity between your Android and that site - due to your router / firewall setup?